# Cambiar valores ScripteableObject de un objeto en tiempo de ejecución en Unity

Tags: unity

Tengo un prefab de un soldado en un juego. Este prefab tiene una componente Arma, la cual tiene varios atributos como un nombre y la última vez que disparó. Además tiene un atributo que he llamado ValoresArma y que hace referencia a un ScripteableObject con datos como daño, cadencia, rango, precisión...

Cuando se quiera mejorar un arma, quiero que todos los soldados aliados que tengan ese arma, reciban esa mejora, cambiando por tanto los datos de ese atributo ValoresArma por los de otro ScripteableObject.

Tengo en el código algo de este estilo:

```
if(mejora)
  weapon.WeaponValues = ...
```

¿Qué podría poner en los puntos suspensivos? En definitiva, ¿cómo hago ese cambio?

Answer (score 0):

En primer termino te comento que para un cambio dinámico de diferentes `ScriptableObjects` te recomiendo tener una clase como la de a continuación:

```
/// WeaponList.cs ///

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "WeaponList", menuName "Crear/Weapon List")]
public class WeaponList : ScriptableObject{

   [SerializeField]
   public List<Weapon> weapons = new List<Weapon>();

   [System.Serializable]
   public struct Weapon{
      ///Propiedades de las Armas///
   }
}
```

Donde podras usar la siguiente clase como gestora:

```
/// WeaponsManager.cs ///

/// Este Script deberias agregarlo a un objeto
vacío en cada escena donde vayan a haber Soldados. ///

public class WeaponsManager : MonoBehaviour{ 
   private List<Soldier> soldados = new List<Soldier>(); /// Agregados cuando se instancien o aparezcan en escena en un metodo Awake() o Start() ///
   static WeaponList.Weapon currentWeapon; /// Estatico para que se mantenga entre escenas. ///

   public void AddSoldier(Soldier soldier){
      soldados.Add(soldier);
   }

   public void UpdateAllSoldiersWeapon(){
      for(int i = 0; i < soldiers.Count; i++){
         soldados[i].weapon = currentWeapon();
      }
   }

   public WeaponList.Weapon SetCurrentWeapon{
      set
      {
         currentWeapon = value;
      }
   }
}
```

En segundo termino aclaro que soy plenamente desconociente de clases que emplees y tengas definidas, te recomiendo ampliamente que la próxima vez agregues mas información a tu pregunta para facilitar la adaptabilidad del código resultante.

Y en tercer termino aclaro que para funcionar desde la logica de los soldados el gestor de armas es tan simple como crear una referencia al mismo o hacer una llamada, como por ejemplo `GameObject.FindObjectOfType<WeaponManager>().AddSoldier(this)`. Suerte en tu proyecto. Saludos.